# Could not find com.android.extensions.build:gradle:4.1.1 - (repo mavenCentral used)

Tags: flutter, gradle

Really don't know if the issue is related to some issue in my configuration but, starting some days ago, I started having problems compiling.
While including the package cryptography_flutter in pubspec.yaml when compiling for Android I obtain the following:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':cryptography_flutter'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':cryptography_flutter:classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.extensions.build:gradle:4.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/extensions/build/gradle/4.1.1/gradle-4.1.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/extensions/build/gradle/4.1.1/gradle-4.1.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :cryptography_flutter
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':cryptography_flutter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':cryptography_flutter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Answer (score 1):

This package seems to be an older one and may throw an error if you are running flutter 3. Try downgrading flutter if this is an important package or in pubspec.yaml change the version to any and try again